# strsplit() behaves different with space at the beginning and end of string

Tags: r, strsplit

Depending on if the split criteria (`' '`) is at the beginning or end of a string, it shows up as an item in the output list.

```
#strsplit("This is a string ")

strsplit("This is a string ", ' ')
#[[1]]
#[1] "This"   "is"     "a"      "string"

#strsplit(" And this is a string", ' ')
strsplit(" And this is a string", ' ')
#[[1]]
#[1] ""       "And"    "this"   "is"     "a"      "string"
```

Is there a way to alter this code so that the space shows up as an item for both lists?

Intended output:

```
#strsplit("This is a string ")

strsplit("This is a string ", ' ')
#[[1]]
#[1] "This"   "is"     "a"      "string" "" 

#strsplit(" And this is a string", ' ')
strsplit(" And this is a string", ' ')
#[[1]]
#[1] ""       "And"    "this"   "is"     "a"      "string"
```

Comment: Note that this is documented behavior at `?strsplit` in the "details" section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `stringi::stri_split`

```
require(stringi)
stri_split_fixed("This is a string ", ' ')
#[[1]]
#[1] "This"   "is"     "a"      "string" ""      

stri_split_fixed(" And this is a string", ' ')
#[[1]]
#[1] ""       "And"    "this"   "is"     "a"     
#[6] "string"
```

Comment: Or `library(ore); ore.split(" ", "this is a string ")`.